# Z-Index and javascript for rollover

Tags: javascript, css, z-index, rollover

I have a container (div) with a background image. In this div there is a menu - a horizontal list. What I need is to insert an image onMouseOver, positioning it absolutely, and showing it behind the text (of course!) AND on top of the div's background image. I also use jQuery, but I think this doesn't matter. The problem can be viewed online.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    img {
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      position:absolute;
      z-index:-1;
    }

    #main {
      color: red;
      margin: 30px;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 700px;
      min-height: 400px;
      z-index: -2;
      background-image: url("http://www.google.com/logos/mother10-hp.gif");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>Z-Index question:</h1>
    <img src="w3css.gif" width="100" height="140" />
    <p>How can we place the green pic between the text and the div#main?</p>
    <p>I need the green gif to appear</p>
    <ol>
      <li>On top of #main's background image</li>
      <li>Behind the text</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need `position:relative;`, `absolute` or `fixed` on a div for the `z-index` to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [the W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp):

> z-index only works on positioned
>   elements (`position:absolute`,
>   `position:relative`, or `position:fixed`).

Answer (score 0):

I made this work for your example. Hope it helps.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      .img1 {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:2;
      }
      #wrapper {
        background-image: url("http://www.google.com/logos/mother10-hp.gif");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        z-index:1;
        width:600px;
        height:600px;
      }
      #main {
        color: red;
        margin: 30px;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 700px;
        min-height: 400px;
        z-index: 3;
        position:absolute;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="img1">
        <img src="w3css.gif" width="100" height="140" />
      </div>
      <div id="main">
        <h1>Z-Index question:</h1>
        <p>How can we place the green pic between the text and the div#main?</p>
        <p>I need the green gif to appear</p>
        <ol>
          <li>On top of #main's background image</li>
          <li>Behind the text</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can only use z-index on positioned elements, here the wrapper is not positioned, yet it is sandwiched between the two divs. As I said, this works for the example posted, and isn't 100% accurate, you will have to add positioning for your other elements in your project. :)